# keyboard not working sometime at logon

Tags: keyboard, 20.04

I upgraded recently to 20.04 and I face an issue since then; I install it on all my home computers (5) and one only have a strange behavior, laptop Dell Inspiron 13 (7000 Series).
The issue is that when the screen is locked, and only sometimes, the keyboard is not working to logon with the password; I restart the machine by forcing the shut down and then it works again. I don't really know when exactly it does this as sometimes when the screen is locked it works...
Any help, it is annoying to loose all my work just because the screen get locked...

thank you

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried updating my kernel to 5.7.1 but that did not help. As a temporary measure I've disabled the screen lock on suspend. Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock